# Can I develop XNA games without an XNACC subscription?

Tags: xna, xbox360

I'm looking forward to buying an Xbox 360 Slim 4GB to get started with XNA development. Can I develop games/apps on my Windows PC and [deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975643.aspx) them to the Xbox without a Creators Club subscription? I'm not looking at publishing my work or putting it up on a marketplace.

And does this model of Xbox 360 support game deployment and storage? I heard that it doesn't. Can anyone confirm which model of Xbox I should purchase to begin XNA development? If I buy the 4GB Slim what development features would not be supported?

[One MSDN deployment article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975643.aspx) says:

> At the very least, you will need a Silver Xbox LIVE membership, an XNA Creators Club premium membership, and a hard drive for your Xbox 360 console to be able to develop games for Xbox 360 using XNA Game Studio.

Another [deployment technique article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203929.aspx) is a little ambiguous.

Comment: You cannot deploy to the 4GB Slim without buying MS's special hard drive. You'd be better off buying an older Xbox (which is probably why you asked your other question about deployment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're a student, head over to www.dreamspark.com and you can get a free one year Creators Club subscription. It doesn't include access to the premium materials on the website, but it is enough to deploy to your 360.